# Adding Date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Have this simple table:

```
Name
-----
test1
test2
test3
```

And I need to build something like this:

```
Name    Year    Month
---------------------
Test1   2016    1
Test1   2016    2
Test1   2016    3
Test1   2016    …
Test1   2016    12
Test2   2016    1
Test2   2016    2
Test2   2016    3
Test2   2016    …
Test2   2016    12
Test1   2017    1
Test1   2017    2
Test1   2017    3
Test1   2017    …
Test1   2017    12
Test2   2017    1
Test2   2017    2
Test2   2017    3
Test2   2017    …
Test2   2017    12
```

Can someone give me a hint please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: join with a [Calendar table](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

Comment: Thanks Tim,
Off course, it has been a hard week...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select * 
from mytable
Cross join dateTable

It has been a hard week, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick option if you don't have a Calendar table

```
Select * 
 From  YourTable
 Cross Join ( values (2016),(2017) ) Y(Year)
 Cross Join ( values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12) ) M(Month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a calendar table, absolutely invaluable,.

Here's a [tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) by Aaron Bertrand of SentryOne.